# Reset directory owner

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh, root, chown

Believeing I was in another directory I accidentally ran the following command on the root:

```
sudo chown -R j:root /
```

*My username is j*

Unfortunately because of this I am unable to run any `sudo` commands and undo my mistake, as the server can no longer access the `sudo` file. I am also unable to login via SSH as the file that controls that is also inaccessible!

I have physical access to the device - Is there a way to undo my mistake?

Comment: No, reinstall your system.

Comment: You can try, but it is less reliable and takes longer then reinstalling.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, it wouldn't matter in which directory you were while running that command, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is recovery mode on desktop versions but I don't know whether it exists on sever versions. It can drop a rootshell, so maybe stop reading my answer and check out whether it exists.

If it doesn't, you can chroot into the system if you can boot into a live session. So do the latter and execute these commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxY /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/sdzY /mnt/boot # THIS LINE ONLY WHEN USING A DEDICATED BOOT PARTITION!!!
sudo mount /dev/sdwY /mnt/boot/efi # THIS LINE ONLY WHEN USING UEFI!!!
sudo mount -t devtmpfs /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -t devpts /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo mount -t tmpfs /run /mnt/run
```

Replace `/dev/sdxY` with your system partition, `/dev/sdzY` with your boot partition, and `/dev/sdwY` with your efi partition (but why the hell would you be using uefi anyway!?).

And then run `sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash` to chroot into the other system. You can exit via `exit`.

Comment: Thank you for your superb answer - In the end I reinstalled the server as it was a new install but hopefully your answer will provide assistance to silly people like me in the future!